# Как в lua api передавать объект класса из одной функции в другую

Tags: c++, lua

Как в lua api c++ передавать объект класса   из одной функции в другую?

Одна функция возвращает объект класса,  другая функция получает в качестве параметра этот объект, она должна вызвать метод класса  этого объекта.  У меня не получается передать через   объект класса  для вызова метода.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"include/lua.hpp"

using namespace std;

struct a{   int x = 0;
    a() {cout <<"jn"  << endl;
        this->x = x;}

    void get() {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};

int set(lua_State *L) {// передаем указатель на состояние
    //a s;//значение переменной по умолчанию.
    a ** s = (a **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(a *)); 
    lua_getglobal(L, "a"); /* Использовать глобальную таблицу Sprite в качестве метатабельной */
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    return 1;// вернуть 2.
}
int get(lua_State *L) {// передаем указатель на состояние   

    if (LUA_TUSERDATA == lua_type(L, 1)) {// если это польз. данные.
        a *p = (a*)lua_touserdata(L, 1);
        p->get();
    }
    return 1;// вернуть 1.
}
int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);//открыть все стандартные библиотеки lua.
    lua_pushcfunction(L, set);//уст указатель на функцию C++ и создает внутри Lua
    lua_setglobal(L, "set"); //получает значение из стека и уст значение global name.
    lua_pushcfunction(L, get);//уст указатель на функцию C++ и создает внутри Lua
    lua_setglobal(L, "get"); //получает значение из стека и уст значение global name.
    luaL_dofile(L, "main.lua");/* Загружает и запускает заданный файл. файл в 
         которым все происходит.*/
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);// вызов функции в lua файле.
    lua_close(L);// закрыть состояние
    cin.get();//ожидает ввода символа программа завершается.
    return 0;
}

lua

sp=set()

get(sp)
```

Comment: Что-то тут непонятно написано. *"не получается передать через объект класса для вызова метода"* - что не получается-то? Если проблема в приведенном коде, то укажите, что вы ожидаете получить, что получаете на самом деле и с какого момента оно начинает идти не так. *"return 1;// вернуть 1."* - очень полезный комментарий

Answer (score 0):

получилось!!!!!!!

```
struct a {  int x = 0;
    a() : x() { }//конструктор по умолчанию
    void show() { cout << " x = " << x << endl; }~a() { }//вызов деструктора.
};

int create(lua_State* L) {//    Функция создания объекта структуры.
    void* st = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(a));/*Эта функция выделяет новый блок памяти с заданным размером,*/
    new (st) a();// Выделить память под польз. данные.
    luaL_getmetatable(L, "aMetaTable"); /* отправляет в стек метатаблицу значения при заданном приемлемом индексе.*/
    lua_setmetatable(L, 1);//получает таблицу из стека и уст ее в качестве новой метатаблицы для значения с заданным допустимым индексом.
    return 1;};

int destroy(lua_State* L) {// Функция вызывает деструктор для объекта.
    a* st = (a*)lua_touserdata(L, 1);/* Если значение в данном приемлемом индексе является полными данными пользователя.*/
    st->~a();//вызов метода деструктор.
    return 0;};

int show(lua_State* L) {
    a* st = (a*)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
    st->show();
    return 0;};


int main() {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    lua_newtable(L);
    int stTableIdx = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_pushvalue(L, stTableIdx);// отправляет копию элемента с заданным допустимым индексом в стек.
    lua_setglobal(L, "a");// Установить значение глобальной переменной.
    lua_pushcfunction(L, create);//уст указатель на функцию C++ и создает внутри Lua
    lua_setglobal(L, "new"); //получает значение из стека и уст значение global name.
    lua_pushcfunction(L, show);
    lua_setglobal(L, "show"); //получает значение из стека и уст значение global name.
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "aMetaTable");/*int luaL_newmetatable (lua_State * L, const char 
    * t); */
    lua_pushstring(L, "__gc");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, destroy);
    lua_settable(L, 2);
    luaL_dofile(L, "main.lua");// Загружает и запускает заданный файл. файл в которым 
     все        происходит.
    lua_close(L);// закрыть состояние
    cin.get();//ожидает ввода символа программа завершается.
return 0;
}
```